# What are the chances of a claiming a .com domain name from a squatter

Tags: domains, domain-registration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Purchasing a Domain from a Domain Squatter](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/purchasing-a-domain-from-a-domain-squatter)

As the question states, if a .com domain is squatted by the usual ad site, what are the chances of getting the domain (not buying it from the squatter)? And what should one expect to spend on it? **This is for a startup company**, is it still possible?

Any past experiences are very welcome.

Also does the standard default ad site make a difference? What if the domain is owned, but no website is setup at the domain? I realize there are other uses, but for those cases a subdomain is usually "enough".

Comment: This is not a duplicate, please read the questions. I'm not looking to buy the domain from the squatter, but to claim the rights to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parked domains with ad's are not squatted domains. They are usually domains which have expired and were registered by a company just to earn some ad revenue from whatever traffic the domain may still be getting.

You can make an offer, any offer that's up to you. Your chances are better if the domain has little traffic and is earning the company little to nothing.

Comment: I see, an annoying business model.
I was hoping it wasn't a valid reason to keep a domain.

Comment: Some registrars even register the deleted domains enoms.com i've seen do it and once they have them I don't think there is much you can do to register them again.