# Where can I download list of all .com domains registered in the world

Tags: domains

I just need registered .com domain names.

I know this list is available at:

- http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/grow-your-domain-name-business/tld-zone-access/index.xhtml ( looks like it could take 4 weeks for approval)
- http://www.premiumdrops.com/zones.html
- Also I can extract domain names using domain search API at domaintools.com

Is there any other source where I can find this list?

Comment: You do realize that, by the time you've downloaded the list, it will already be obsolete?

Comment: Time accuracy will affect my result by .1% only.

Comment: You answered your own question in the question itself, or is there something wrong with the lists you mentioned?

Comment: You can get a list of all registered domains, dropped domains, and newly registered domains at http://www.domaindatapro.com - also, this service provides you with daily lists of newly registered domain names and their whois contact information: http://www.easywhoispro.com